# Construction of lissajous figure from equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, kinematics, harmonic-oscillator, oscillators

So I was solving questions from my workbook and came across this problem. I don't know how to solve this.
QUESTION: **Two vibrations at right angles to one another is described by the equations x=10cos(5πt), y=10(5πt+π/3). Construct the Lissajous figure of the combined motion.**

Comment: The question seems to be asking you to plot a graph. I assume that the function for y is supposed to be a sine rather than a linear function?

Comment: Lissajous figures are just parametric $(x,y)$ plots, check [this example with desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/65kztevpxk). Btw, you forgot $\cos()$ (or $\sin$) function for the $y$ axis.